# Split lists by half of their lengths in R

Tags: r, list

I have a tibble with variable, that contains a lists. Each list has a different lengths. I would like to have two new variables, let’s say “lon” and “lat”. In variable “lon” I’d like to have first half of each list, and in variable “lat” the second half.

data:

```
file_url <- "https://github.com/slawomirmatuszak/Covid.UA/raw/master/sample.Rda?raw=true"
load(url(file_url))
```

I can achieve that by filtering lists, but I’d like to do this by more universal code (based on lengths, not a specific number).

```
sample.data$lon <- lapply(sample.data$geometry, function(x) unlist(x)[x<40])
sample.data$lat <- lapply(sample.data$geometry, function(x) unlist(x)[x>40])
```

Comment: Do you mean you'll have more than 2 columns in `geometry` like 8 and you want to create two new columns with 4 columns each?

Comment: I need to have two new columns. One with first half of the list elements from geometry column, and the second column with the other half of  list elements from geometry column.

Comment: You should probably just use `st_geometry()` from the `sf` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you can try with `length` to get first half and second half  of `geometry` column.

```
sample.data$lat <- sapply(sample.data$geometry, function(x) 
                      {tmp <- unlist(x);tmp[1:(length(tmp)/2)]})
sample.data$lon <- sapply(sample.data$geometry, function(x) 
                      {tmp <- unlist(x);tmp[((length(tmp)/2) + 1):length(tmp)]})
```